# How do I remove the top bar and bottom bar from the Students Mathematica window?

Tags: front-end, notebooks, options, customization

- Any idea how to remove the top bar saying

  > "Wolfram Mathematica .... Demonstrations MathWorld Studenforum Help"

  from the *Mathematica* main window (see screenshot). It has no use to me and it steals real estate from my laptop sreen.
- **Also**: How do I remove the bottom bar with the zoom button?

Appreciate any help!

[image: frontend]

*keywords*: student's edition dockedcells toolbar

Comment: You can upload images to an upload server. Post the link here and we'll include the image in the question.

Comment: I think that's part of the student version. When I upgraded to the full license, it disappeared. There was a very brief discussion about this over at the [Student Support Forum](http://forums.wolfram.com/student-support/topics/24032/), and the official line is that you can't remove it.

Answer (score 12):

In Mathematica catalog, in subfolder TextResources you'll find a file called MiscExpressions.tr.

Simply replace 
    `"StudentBar"-> Cell[BoxData[...]]`
with
    `"StudentBar"-> Cell[]`

There are two things to remember though:

1. This might not be a legal thing to do.
2. It's best not to modify the original file, instead save the modified file in your Mathematica $UserBaseDirectory under the same directory structure as the original file. This will make Mathematica use your new file, leaving the old one untouched.

Comment: This works for Ubuntu 16.04 also

Comment: It still works in **Mathematica 12.1**

Answer (score 10):

```
SetOptions[InputNotebook[], "DockedCells" -> None]
```

Comment: The structure of notebooks in the student version is the same as the full version, but I'm not sure how to automatically remove them for all new notebooks, shouldn't be too hard

Comment: Nice...if that could be automatically...

Comment: try to put in an init.m file, but careful this may interfere with slide mode that has docked cells.

Comment: Looks like this method doesn't work for Mathematica 9 for Students, any ideas on a fix?

Answer (score 6):

Top bar case solved so about the bottom bar, you can drop some things from:

```
Options[EvaluationNotebook[], WindowElements]
```

> ```
> {WindowElements -> {"StatusArea", "MemoryMonitor", "MagnificationPopUp", 
>     "HorizontalScrollBar", "VerticalScrollBar", "MenuBar"}}
> ```

Like `"StatusArea","MagnificationPopUp", "HorizontalScrollBar"`:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], WindowElements -> {
   "MemoryMonitor", "VerticalScrollBar", "MenuBar"}
]
```

---

There is also `WindowFrame` option for a notebook and some of them have less elements included. Edge example is `"Frameless"` but it behaves strangely according to my experience.

Comment: You can also drop `"MemoryMonitor"`. ["It is obsolete, ..."](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/97810/what-is-memorymonitor#comment265629_97810).

Comment: Nice, `SetOptions[$FrontEnd, 
 WindowElements -> {"VerticalScrollBar"}]` is very minimalistic. `SetOptions[$FrontEnd, 
 WindowElements -> (WindowElements /. 
    Options[$DefaultFrontEnd, WindowElements])]` brings back the defaults.