# What is "MemoryMonitor"?

Tags: front-end, notebooks, customization

Evaluating one of the following inputs

```
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], WindowElements]

CurrentValue[$FrontEndSession, WindowElements]

CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, WindowElements]

Options[EvaluationNotebook[], WindowElements]

Options[$FrontEndSession, WindowElements]

Options[$FrontEnd, WindowElements]
```

reveals that the default notebook window contains an element called `"MemoryMonitor"`.
I did not see any change after removing it with

```
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], WindowElements] = 
 DeleteCases[CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], WindowElements], "MemoryMonitor"]
```

Therefore my question is:
What is `"MemoryMonitor"` or what's it good for and why shouldn't I remove it?

---

By default the special kinds of notebooks created with the following comments don't have any `WindowElements`:

- `CreatePalette`
- `CreateWindow@PaletteNotebook`
- `CreateDialog`
- `CreateWindow@DialogNotebook`
- `MessageDialog`

Comment: I'm using *Mathematica* v10.3 under Windows 10, if that matters.

Comment: It is obsolete, Mac-only functionality that has been removed from the front-end about 13 years ago.

Comment: @ilian But why is it still one of the default `WindowElements`? Shouldn't it be removed, if it's obsolete? It's just pollution now.

Comment: I don't know.. probably just an oversight. There is no actual code behind it.

Comment: @ilian Thank you for the clarification. I just removed it with `CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, WindowElements] = 
 DeleteCases[CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, WindowElements], "MemoryMonitor"]`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think it is a vestigial artifact of older days when systems had only a few megabytes of memory and *Mathematica* was always in danger of running out of kernel memory. I don't think it makes any difference whether or not you remove the specification string "MemoryMonitor" in any recent version, because the widget it controlled no longer exists.

Similarly, on OS X, it doesn't make any difference whether or not I remove the specification string "MenuBar", because the OS X version of *Mathematica* doesn't implement window-specific menu bars.