How to remove unexpected menuebar in notebook?
While working with a notebook an additional blue bar popped up:

Don't know how it happens.
My Question: How could I remove this "blue bar"?
Thanks!

Maybe M.R.’s answer  (https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9471/how-do-i-remove-the-top-bar-and-bottom-bar-from-the-students-mathematica-window/101062#101062).  If that doesn’t work, perhaps modifying it toMenuBar->None ?

@CraigCarter Thanks, SetOptions[InputNotebook[], "DockedCells" -> None] works!

Or SetOptions[ EvaluationNotebook[], StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb" ] if you accidentally applied a "Form Notebook Authring" stylesheet.

@Kuba Thanks for your hint. Still I have no idea how(and where) I changed the stylesheet
